# Reduce whitespace around regression tables using huxtable()

Tags: r, r-markdown

HI: I am using huxtable() and Rmarkdown to report a regression table in a Microsoft Word document. Huxtable is working great, but its default produces regression tables with significant whitespace around the cells. 
The table I am reporitn is large and so I really need to minimize whitespace, but this code using map_bottom_padding() does not seem to do anything.

````
```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "author"
date: '2019-09-16'
output: word_document
---    

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
var1<-rnorm(100)
var2<-rnorm(100)
depvar1<-rnorm(100)
model1<-lm(depvar1~var1+var2)

library(tidyverse)
library(huxtable)
library(flextable)

huxreg(model1) %>% 
set_font_size(6) %>% 
map_bottom_padding(., 
by_cols(1,0.5))

```
````

Comment: Huxtable author here. Go nuclear with `set_all_padding` and see if that works. If not, report an issue.

Comment: Hmm. (1) probably you want to not set bottom padding by column, because the largest bottom padding is going to win. (2) Even if you do `set_all_padding(0)`, Word still seems to put big gaps between the cells. (The padding does indeed get smaller, though.) You could try setting `row_height`. If that fails, maybe explicitly call as_flextable, and use some of those functions. Feel free to file a bug report at github too.

Comment: Thanks. `row_height` is the way to go. See below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my own case, using a combination of `set_row_height()` and forcing the column width to be smaller with `set_col_width()` worked really well. For some reason `set_row_height()` does not seem to affect the tables produced in the reproducible code. However, if anyone stumbles across this, fiddling with these two arguments will work.

```
var1<-rnorm(100)
var2<-rnorm(100)
depvar1<-rnorm(100)
model1<-lm(depvar1~var1+var2)

library(tidyverse)
library(huxtable)
library(flextable)

huxreg(model1) %>% 
set_font_size(6) %>% 
  set_row_height(., everywhere, 0.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

For a Quarto document, I found that `set_row_height()` did nothing but `set_all_padding(0)` as recommended by @dash2 worked.

```
var1<-rnorm(100)
var2<-rnorm(100)
depvar1<-rnorm(100)
model1<-lm(depvar1~var1+var2)

library(huxtable)

huxreg(model1) |>
  set_font_size(10) |> 
  set_all_padding(0)
```

Works for .pdf and .html formats.